# Mqtt check if subscribed topic has stopped publishing messages

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I am trying to implement a way to know when a specific device has stopped publishing messages to an mqtt broker and in that case send an email to myself. I want to do this to be able to know if there is a problem with the device that is publishing the messages so I can check it and turn it back on. To try to accomplish this I created a mqtt client that subscribes to the topic that the device publishes e.g. test/device_1 and then set as last will and testament for that device status/device_1 where I put as payload="Offline". Ideally, I want to be able to do this for more than 1 device, but let's assume I just want it for the simple case of one device.

I created another script that implements another client that is subscribed to the topic status/device_1 and then on the on_message function it checks if it gets the payload="Offline" and if it does get it then I send an email to myself.

This approach however doesn't work as when I turn off my device, the mqtt client that is subscribed to the topic test/device_1 keeps listening but gets no messages. In other words, it doesn't send its last will even when the topic is empty. However, it seems to work when I stop the script that is subscribed to the topic test/device_1.

Am I missing something or is it not possible to accomplish what I am trying to do? Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `last timestamp` when device published the messages as heartbeat and in your another script, if `(current_time - last_timestamp) > 30` then you can email yourself that your device is offline. this way you can have threshold of time when you want to get email of device offline.

script 1:

```
mqttCient.on_message(msg):
    last_timestamp = time.time()
```

script 2:

```
cur_time = time.time()
if ((cur_time - last_timestamp) > 30):
    # email yourself
```

use `Json` file or database as buffer for storing and accessing `last_timestamp`

Comment: I was thinking of something similar but how can I email myself only once after 30 seconds and if the device goes online and then offline again, then be able to email myself again?

Comment: I think you are expecting email every time when device goes offline for more then 30 seconds, that if if device gets offline you get email and if device get online within 30 seconds again, you will don't get email(assuming this is not an concern). If you want mails each time for device getting offline and online. you can decrease the `threshold`   to 5 seconds. it will ensure that you get mails most of time when your device gets offline

Answer (score 2):

First LWT messages are only published by the broker if the client goes offline unexpectedly, which means if it shuts down cleanly then it will not get published, you have to manually publish a message as part of shut down process.

You can set the retained flag on the LWT so that any client that subscribes after the device has gone offline it will still see the state message.

You should also clear that message on when the device starts up, either by publishing something like `Online` or a `null` payload to clear the retained message.

Comment: How can I manually publish a message as part of shut down process? How could I identify a shutdown process?

Comment: That depends how you are ending your script, but assuming you are using ctrl-c then you'll need to add a signal handler.

Comment: The problem doesn't exist when I turn off the script. The script should run forever. The problem exists when I turn off the device. The client implemented by the script keeps listening but gets zero messages. That is the case that I want to catch and get notified by an email.

Comment: if you just power the device off (no graceful shutdown) then the LWT will fire at 1.5 * the keepalive time

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. So I tried to do it with this way. I put the keepalive period=10 and when I turn off my device every 10 seconds the client sends PINGREQ and receives PINGRESP. Thus the LWT never fires. How can it receive PINGRESP even if I turn my device off. Additionally, I tried modifying the client code to supress the PINGREQ and PINGRESP and then I run into another problem as every 10 seconds the client reconnects and then disconnects again. Thus, the LWT gets sent every 15 seconds. Is there a way I can fix this?